# NGXS: how can we pass entire collection to the actions in ngxs?

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am having a collection of object which I need to pass to ngxs actions. I am able to pass single object and it is storing the state and working fine but i do not want to iterate the object instead want to pass entire collection?

I have tried for single object it is working fine, but want to pass entire collection?

I am trying like this but it is not working:

```
export class AddAccounts {
  static readonly type = '[Account] Add';
  constructor(public payload: Account[]) { }
}

//this.accounts is a collection of Account[] type.
this.store.dispatch(this.accounts); 

export class AccountStateModel {
  accounts: Account[][];
}

@State<AccountStateModel>({
  name: 'accounts',
  defaults: {
    accounts: []
  }
})

@Selector()
static getAccounts(state: AccountStateModel) {
  return state.accounts;
}

@Action(AddAccount)
add({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<AccountStateModel>, { payload }: 
  AddAccount) {
  const state = getState();
  patchState({
    accounts: [...state.accounts, payload]
  });
}
```

Is there a way we can pass entire collection to the actions?

Comment: Is it just that in your call to dispatch you aren't creating the action type .. it should be `this.store.dispatch(new AddAccount(this.accounts));` ?

Comment: Thanks Garth, with this it is creating next state as:                                            
next state {accounts: {…}}                                                                          
       accounts: accounts: [Array(4)]                                                       
                      __proto__: Object__proto__: Object                                                          and i am using selector as: @Select(AccountState.getAccounts) accounts$: Observable<Account[]>; but i am not getting any thing in my component.

Comment: I made a stackblitz with your code, seems to work ok - I can see 'accounts' appearing in a component see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3dheum

Comment: Garth, I can see in console that i am getting array in new state but it is inside array of array but it is not appearing in UI. @Select(AccountState.getAccounts) accounts$: Observable<Account[]>;  html: "accounts$ | async", console:  next state {accounts: {…}}accounts: accounts: [Array(4)]__proto__:

Comment: Maybe some issue with your template, can you post a stackblitz or some more complete code in the question?

Comment: Garth, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jprbvq . This is dummy code where I am adding a collection from create component and want the value to be displayed in read component which is not coming.

Comment: I can't see anything on that blitz it's just the starter template ..

Comment: sorry! plz try now may be i forgot to save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just an error in your state model.
The `TutorialStateModel` was defined as an array of arrays (`Tutorial[][]`) rather than a single array.

When I update your definition, and fix the `patchState` call to match it, I can see the UI updating as I'd expect.  See below:

[image]